# Angular $resource not delivering the right data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

Inside my controller I'm making the following API call:

```
weatherApp.controller('forecastController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'cityService', function($scope, $resource, cityService){
    $scope.city = cityService.city;

    $scope.weatherAPI = $resource('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily', {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}, {get: {method: 'JSONP'}});
    $scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI.get({ q: $scope.city, cnt: 4, APPID: 'xxxxxx' });

    console.log($scope.weatherResult)
}]);
```

I'm getting a promise in return but it didn't return the right information and wasn't able to fetch data.

[image: Error]

I think the problem is with how I'm inserting my API Key into the call. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is that api jsonp enabled? Not all are

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using? The current docs say not to use `JSON_CALLBACK`

Comment: I'm using `1.3.0-rc.2`

Comment: Do you have to? I mean, even using a stable 1.3 build instead of a release candidate would be far more preferable

Comment: For this particular project, I do, unfortunately. :/

Comment: [I think with 1.3](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/docs/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) you have to set the JSONP callback in the URL, eg `$resource('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {}, { get: ... })`. Try that

Comment: @charlietfl seems they do ~ https://openweathermap.org/forecast16#call

Comment: `net::ERR_ABORTED` seems like you simply can't connect. Make sure your `APPID` hasn't been blocked or anything like that

Comment: @Phil Thanks for all the comments. That was my initial thought but I signed up and got the Key around 30 mins ago and the key itself is fine.

The problem def seems to be around there though:

https://i.imgur.com/UF9NxoX.png

Comment: What does the response actually look like, ie the headers and response body? You should be able to see all that in your *Network* console. A 401 response status indicates your API key is invalid

Comment: Hey Phil. So I did a little more research and found out that `callback :'JSON_CALLBACK' ` is deprecated so I removed that. I also saw that the daily forecast is no longer available so I took that out as well from the request url. I'm still getting an unresolved promise though.  The headers under network now show that i'm getting a 404, the city was not found (I'm using "New York, NY" as an example). [headers](https://i.imgur.com/hnw3a7b.png)

Answer (score 0):

So I kind of managed to solve it and got a promise in return with the following code:

```
weatherApp.controller('forecastController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'cityService', function($scope, $resource, cityService){
    $scope.city = cityService.city;

    $scope.weatherAPI = $resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/?APPID=d98c063da512b5ab03e39ac4a158b41f", {
    get: {method: "JSONP"}});

    $scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI.get({q: $scope.city, cnt: 5});


    console.log($scope)
    console.log($scope.weatherResult)
}]);
```

I removed `callback :'JSON_CALLBACK'` since it's deprecated and will give an error. I also removed `daily` from the request URL since it's no longer provided and replaced it with `forecast` as seen in the [API docs](http://openweathermap.org/current#name). Now, previously I was placing in a param for the city as "New York, NY" but for some odd reason openweathermap api doesn't need the state(? Someone correct me if I'm wrong on this). So I removed the state and left it with the city on its own -> i.e. "New York", "New Orleans", "London", etc.

This seems to be returning a promise with the right data.